# AttributeError 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'outer_context'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I'm building a basic sentiment analysis model using a pretrained elmo model, but the interpreter stops at at the `model.fit()` line due to the error `AttributeError 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'outer_context'` in spite of the fact that I am passing my input text to `model.fit()` as a numpy array

I'm loading elmo locally

```
elmo_path = r"C:\Users\name\Downloads\elmo"
elmo_module = hub.KerasLayer(elmo_path)
```

followed by a super basic model definition

```
input_text = keras.layers.Input(shape=(), dtype=tf.string)
embeddings = elmo_module(input_text)
dense = keras.layers.Dense(256, activation="relu")(embeddings)
predictions = keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")(dense)
model = keras.Model(inputs=[input_text], outputs=predictions)
```

convert lemmatized training data to numpy array

```
X_train_lemmatized = np.asarray(X_train_lemmatized)
```

compile my model

```
model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer="adam", metrics=["accuracy"])
```

and then fit it on some lemmatized training data (which has already been converted to a numpy array)

```
model.fit(X_train_lemmatized, y_train, epochs=1, batch_size=64)
```

Here is the complete error message. It looks to me like the `tape` variable isn't being initialised properly?

```
    File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1160, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1146, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1135, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 997, in train_step
        self.optimizer.minimize(loss, self.trainable_variables, tape=tape)
    File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\keras\optimizers\optimizer_v2\optimizer_v2.py", line 576, in minimize
        grads_and_vars = self._compute_gradients(
    File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\keras\optimizers\optimizer_v2\optimizer_v2.py", line 634, in _compute_gradients
        grads_and_vars = self._get_gradients(
    File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\keras\optimizers\optimizer_v2\optimizer_v2.py", line 510, in _get_gradients
        grads = tape.gradient(loss, var_list, grad_loss)

    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'outer_context'
```